# HDD very slow performance after full copy from SSD

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, performance, ssd

The PC: Core i7-4770, 16GB RAM.
There are 120GB SSD and 1TB HDD (new without any bads).

On the SSD I had Windows 8.1 installed with all other stuff. Someday all programs exceeded 120GB limit and I decided to just copy all the things to HDD.
I loaded the PC with Ubuntu Live USB and just `dd` all bytes from SSD to HDD. And with GParted resized partition till 200GB.
After that loading of Windows 8.1 from HDD was unreally slow.
I know how fast Windows 8.1 should work on average HDD, but in my case it was incredibly slow.
I thought that there should be a huge fragmentation, then I run defrag C:. After hour it shows me that there is a zero fragmentation, but Windows with all programs still load very slow.

Strange thing, Windows defrag GUI tool shows me that system partition is on SSD, though it is on HDD already, and unable to perform defragmentation. But console defrag tool just works fine.

Drive with MBR.

Windows is loaded till password prompt in about **60-70s** vs **18s** on an old notebook with HDD.

Visual Studio 2013 cold start takes about **80s**.

Partitions are aligned.

> ---
>
> CrystalDiskMark 3.0.3 x64 (C) 2007-2013 hiyohiyo
>
> ### Crystal Dew World : http://crystalmark.info/
>
> - MB/s = 1,000,000 byte/s [SATA/300 = 300,000,000 byte/s]
>
>   ```
>      Sequential Read :   180.493 MB/s
>     Sequential Write :   169.590 MB/s
>    Random Read 512KB :    42.708 MB/s
>   Random Write 512KB :    67.377 MB/s
>   ```
>
>   Random Read 4KB (QD=1) :     0.434 MB/s [   106.0 IOPS]    Random Write 4KB (QD=1) :     0.877 MB/s [   214.1 IOPS]    Random Read 4KB
>     (QD=32) :     0.868 MB/s [   211.9 IOPS]   Random Write 4KB (QD=32) : 
>     0.910 MB/s [   222.2 IOPS]
>
>   Test : 1000 MB [C: 68.2% (133.2/195.3 GB)] (x5)   Date : 2014/05/21
>     9:32:45
>     OS : Windows 8.1  [6.3 Build 9600] (x64)

Comment: How slow are we talking about?  MBR or GPT?  remove the SSD see if that makes a difference.  We need more specifics

Comment: @Ramhound more than 1 minute before a password prompt. MBR. I removed SSD just after copying from it.

Comment: How can the SSD be shown as being the system drive if you removed it?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know, may be Windows stores some info where it was initially installed, and "Defragment and optimize drives" shows that media type of the system drive is "Solid state drive".

Comment: Could be you can determine if it is a Hard drive communications speed, or some pointers problem where the system is confused and keeps looking in the wrong places? Do a simple HD benchmark test, and see if the HD itself and its communications are all working up to par.  Myself (it is just me) I do not really understand these copy the files over methods, when cloning and imaging methods have a tendancy to fix up a few other things for system drive operations.  In most cases you should (also) have been able to distribute some of the simple data, or large parts of programs over to the HD.

Comment: . . .So you could still use the SSD as originally intended.

Comment: @Psycogeek before I used NTFS symlinks on the SSD for big program folders, placed on HDD. But I decided to use SSD for a linux instead of Windows.

Comment: I see, well there is certannly nothing wrong with the way the HD is working.

Comment: *"just dd all bytes from SSD to HDD."*  -- Exactly what was the command that you used?  Did you specify the entire drive (/dev/sda) or just the partitions (/dev/sda1, /dev/sda2)?

Comment: @sawdust the whole drive.

Comment: Copying the whole drive byte-for-byte is only valid if the drives are identical.  Otherwise you are copying incorrect drive parameters in the MBR.  If you still have the original data on the SSD, then you should redo the copy.  Use Gparted to to create a new partition table on the HDD, and create primary partitions on the HDD the same size as the ones on the SDD.  Then copy partition for partition.

Comment: If your 1TB HDD has 4KB sectors instead of old-style 512 byte sectors, then you need to align the clusters to the 4KB sectors also.

Comment: @sawdust - If that was the problem.  Wouldn't other problems be present.  Like the fact the system wouldn't be able to boot?  Since the boot sector wouldn't be where it was attempting to look at?

Comment: Can you try to do the SSD > HDD clone with Clonezilla? It used to work fine for me.